# `git help` to stdout or to Get-Help (PowerShell)

Tags: git, powershell, manpage

I dislike how `git help` goes to the browser by default on Windows. I know I can change the browser or redirect it to `man` or `info`.

How can I redirect the output to stdout? How can I make it go to `Get-Help`?

Comment: Valid values for the config option `help.format` are `man`, `info` and `html` (a. k. a. `web`), where on Git for Windows `html` is the default. What do you want to redirect where?

Comment: not really powershell related.

Comment: If you're talking about Git for Windows then I think that if you would even succeed to convince it not use HTML pages, there is nothing except them to present you with: [GfW does not bundle `man` pages](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/696). And I'm pretty sure it does not package `info` pages as well.

Answer (score 1):

When in doubt, read the [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-help).

> ### CONFIGURATION VARIABLES
>
> **help.format**
>
> If no command-line option is passed, the *help.format* configuration variable will be checked. The following values are supported for this variable; they make *git help* behave as their corresponding command-line option:
>
> - "man" corresponds to *-m|--man*,
> - "info" corresponds to *-i|--info*,
> - "web" or "html" correspond to *-w|--web*.

On Windows the setting apparently defaults to "web". There is no option for "STDOUT" or PowerShell help.

The closest thing would be to change the help format from "web" to "man" or "info":

```
git config --global help.format man
```

But for that to work you need to have a viewer for man pages (or info pages if you set the format to "info") installed and configured.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I did read the documentation ;) I was hoping there was a way I can view the help from the command line instead of the browser. But yes, it seems I need to find a man.exe or info.exe....

Comment: Yeah, I don't understand this nonsense. Mostly I type something like "git config --gibberish" to see a short info about how to call it (config in this example). I would wish that "--help", would work this way.

Comment: I just realized, calling »bash -c "git help help"« is another way, to achieve this (but WSL is needed, for this to work, and git must also be installed in WSL).